# mage::log() contents of wishlist

Tags: product, wishlist, debugging

Well folks, I need a way to grab the full contents of the wishlist and then log them for examination.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: you mean wishlist products data.

Comment: @Manik okay.  I'd still like an answer to this Q.

Comment: Did you solved? Waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Manik No, i'll put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach(Mage::getModel("wishlist/wishlist")->getItemCollection() as $item) {
    Mage::log($item->getData());
}
```

Haven't tested it, but in case it doesn't work, try `Mage::log(print_r($item->getData(), true));`

Later edit: I've done some testing (you made me curious) and it seems you're not loading the collection properly. Check `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Abstract` for more details, but for debugging you can use the following:

```
   $collection = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('wishlist/customer_wishlist')->getWishlistItems();
   foreach($collection as $item) {
          Mage::log($item->getName(), null, 'wishlist.log', true);
   }
```

Instead of `$item->getName()` you can use getData, getProductName, debug, print_r($tem->getData(),true) and so on.

PS: I've tested this in Wishlist/IndexController:indexAction while logged in.

Comment: This is logging an 'undefined index' error in my catalog/block/product/price.phtml file.  However, I may accept this answer as it seems to be correct -- perhaps it's just an issue with my blocks.  Maybe it's possible to bypass similar issues by just getting the name of the item instead of the totality of the item information?

Comment: it shouldn't throw such an error, the code doesn't access arrays. you could try to log specific data ($item->getData('something')). and i'd suggest using a separate log, like Keyul mentioned - it might be a bit more difficult to follow the info in system.log.

Comment: I changed the log location and it is not created / no information is logged.

Comment: `Mage:log('string', null, 'wishlist.log', true)` doesn't produce anything? if it doesn't, the code doesn't get executed.

Comment: I positioned the log('string') function outside of the foreach loop and that produces a result in the 'wishlist.log' log file.

Comment: and what's the size of the collection? maybe it's empty. Are you loading the collection for a user? i havent check the code, I'm going blind here

Comment: I'm logged into an account and the wishlist itself has numerous items already in it (like twenty from the testing i've done).  The above code i've inserted into the indexcontroller addaction() function.

Comment: i've updated my answer with a proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wish to output a Magento model and you aren't sure what data may be returned by `getData` (specifically if objects may be in the data array), the `Varien_Object::debug()` function is useful.

```
foreach(Mage::getModel("wishlist/wishlist")->getItemCollection() as $item) {
    Mage::log($item->debug());
}
```

In the case of a wishlist item, `getData` would probably work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create your New log file and log the content in this way

```
foreach(Mage::getModel("wishlist/wishlist")->getItemCollection() as $item) {
    Mage::log(print_r($item->getData(),true),null,'wishlist.log');
}
```

> Mage::log(print_r(Mage::getModel("wishlist/wishlist")->getItemCollection(),true),null,'wishlist.log');

To see this log file please look into `var/log/wishlist.log` file.

Comment: getting the same fatal error as below: 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49904868 bytes)'

Comment: I have update the code

Comment: I copied your code exactly into the addAction (so it will be called before an item is added to the wishlist) and nothing is added the wishlist.log file isn't generated / populated.

Comment: they you have to fetch value using observer

Comment: I'm just going to scatter it around the indexcontroller path of action and see if it sticks.  That is a pain in the ass to create an observer just to log wishlist data.  I'm trying to debug some erroneous wishlist functionality that we're observing.  It shouldn't be that complex to just see what it is in the wishlist at each step of the addition / deletion process.